# JQuery UI Autocomplete is slow

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

This code works fine but the problem is that it is slow, I assume it is because it connects to the database everytime I type a letter. Is there a way to make it faster? I have to assume that the db table will not always be the same so I can't just add the results to a var and be done with it. Thank you in advance.

> Also if you believe this api is not good, I can accept alternatives.

**HMTL:**

```
<label for="hint">Meds: </label>
<input id="hint">
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#hint").autocomplete({
        source: 'getMedicineNames.php'
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
require 'connect.inc.php';
$mysql = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass", "$db_name");
$name = isset($_GET['term']) ? $_GET['term'] : "";

if ($name!="") {
    $sql = "SELECT MedicineName FROM medicinetypes WHERE MedicineName LIKE '%$name%'";

    $res = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);
    $res = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach ($res as $row) {
        $data[] = $row['MedicineName'];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: I just want to say the obvious, this code is insecure and is susceptible to an sql-injection attack. It will be slow if you pull from the db, there is no way around that sadly. One thing you could do is pull in an item of each letter and have it at least start off fast and then do more searching once you type more.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the seurity problem? And is there a way to say, get the whole db in a var when the page loads and pass it on the api to do the search client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can investigate in 3 domains:

### Caching

You can implement simple caching systems.

For example, caching all the results of each starting letters in 26 different files or whatever. Find the best repartition for your case. You have many [choices](http://www.php-cache.com/en/latest/) with that approach

### Database optimisation

Does your table have Indexes? If not you WANT to delve into [that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)!

Most of the databases provide some example code for your use case.

### Search Engines

When you have to deal with big datasets, you need to consider using a search engine system (like [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)). 
They usually have built-in modules for autocompleting and are very performant.

Comment: You also have, in addition of that, an option on jQuery UI auto-complete that enables very basic caching on client sides.